# Visual Studio 2015 inconsistent error counts

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a C# project with a lot of sub projects. Could someone explain me how is it possible that building the solution with MSBuild in the CLI gives me less errors than building the solution in the UI? Is Microsoft's stuff really this broken?

Sometimes building the project with MSBuild succeeds (which is correct), but building in the UI succeeds only on a second attempt. Wtf?

If I build, let's say, C++ code with Qt Creator and CMake I get exactly the same result no matter how I build the project.

Comment: Are you building a different configuration by any chance? Or perhaps your dependencies are in the wrong order? It would help if you'd focus on problem instead of the incendiary commentary - can you provide an example that would help us reproduce the problem?

Comment: You should really share the detailed question here instead of giving a broad question. You can test it with a new blank project, check if you still get the same result.